# What will happen if we use 1080x1920 graphic for iPhone 6 Plus?

Tags: ios, iphone

Everyone knows 1242x2208 is the best resolution to design graphic for iPhone 6 Plus.
Launch screens are required to show in 1242x2208 but how about the rest of the images or design?
Will we have pixelated images if we use 1080x1920 for other images?

Thanks

Comment: 1242x2208 will be downscalled to 1080x1920

Comment: Check out this http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Answer (score 0):

My experience has shown that 1080x1920 is sufficient.
1242x2208 is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to use *1080x1920* assets, the only reason they tell you to use *1242x2208* is because it's exactly 3 times *414x736* so the iPhone can easily map points to pixels and then downsample do *1080x1920*.

Just keep in mind that screenshots are always saved in the logical *3×* size (*1242x2208*).

Check out [this page](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) mentioned by [Mike Pollard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1791042/mike-pollard) and don't forget that

> Pixel-perfect rendering is a thing of the past on the iPhone platform - [Ole Begemann](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/11/iphone-6-plus-screen/)